# How to use "page-break-inside" for tbody tag?

Tags: html, css, wkhtmltopdf

I have an HTML file that I convert to PDF using the **Wkhtmltopdf** tool.
I am using  `page-break-inside: avoid` style to escape table wrapping in pages (if there is no place on the current page for the table the whole table goes to a new pdf page), and it works great for tables.

*The question is*

I have this kind of table

```
 <table >
    <caption>Payments</caption>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>line 1</th>
            <td>100.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>line1 note 1</th>
            <td>120.00</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>line1 note 2</th>
            <td>20.00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>line 2</th>
            <td>100.00</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>line2 note 1</th>
            <td>120.00</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <th>line2 note 2</th>
            <td>20.00</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

where each block is tbody inside one big table, as the block can be too long and it can be bigger than one pdf page I want to wrap it by tbody, not by the table. I want the new tbody block to start from the new page (instead of cutting inside tbody block) if there is no place on the current page.
[image]

Comment: I'm just using "page-break-inside: avoid !important;" for tbody elements, but they still wrapping the tbody block instead of moving it to new page,